# multiple components respond to the same ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a WorkComponent that utilises `Activated routes`. In app.module.ts I have:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'data/:project/:detail',component: WorkComponent }
.
.
.
];
```

In work component I use ActivatedRoute params as usual.

but `WorkComponent` isn't the only component that needs to know ActivatedRoute parameters.

for example, in app.component.html I have:

```
<app-navbar>
</app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

NavbarComponent.ts is always present in the app and I would like it to respond the ActivatedRoute parameters as well. I added new route in app.module.ts:

```
{path: 'data/:project/:detail',component: NavbarComponent }
```

And used this code:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
     route.params.subscribe(params => {console.log(params)});
 }
```

//logs empty object.

How can I access params also in NavbarComponent?

Comment: why you wanted to access in both the components?

Comment: both components need to respond to current path.

Comment: Inject ActivateRoute in your NavComponent too

Comment: thats already done and documented in question. sadly, it does not work